# Change style of Google Play Services AccountPicker dialog

Tags: android, dialog, material-design

I am showing the AccountPicker dialog from `Google Play Services` with this code:

```
    String[] accountTypes = new String[]{"com.google"};
    Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
            accountTypes, false, null, null, null, null);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);
```

It appears as a dark themed dialog even though I am using AppCompat v21 with `Theme.AppCompat.Light`.

Is it possible to **style the dialog?** Preferably as a `Material dialog on Lollipop` but at least make it a light dialog to match my app.

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: @AlexSullivan No, I just left it as it is. Now that I look at the code, it looks like it is calling code completely out of my control so it may not be possible to style it. May just need to wait for Google to update their code.

Comment: Oh google. Alright thanks dude.

Answer (score 8):

I think, no need to "hack". It can be achieved easier:

```
    ...
    String[] accountTypes = new String[]{GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE};
    Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, accountTypes, false, description, null, null, null);

    // set the style
    if ( isItDarkTheme ) {
        intent.putExtra("overrideTheme", 0);
    } else {
        intent.putExtra("overrideTheme", 1);
    }
    intent.putExtra("overrideCustomTheme", 0);


    try {
        startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE_PICK_ACCOUNT);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        ...
    }

    ...
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but I finally found the solution. Take a look to *AccountPicker.class*, where are methods: *newChooseAccountIntent()* and *zza()*;

You have to change

```
    AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null, 
accountTypes, false, null, null, null, null);
```

to

```
    AccountPicker.zza(null, null, 
accountTypes, false, null, null, null, null, false, 1, 0);
```

Last two arguments are for "*overrideTheme*" and "*overrideCustomTheme*". So set the first one to 1 and it will override the theme to light. :-)

Hope it helps.

Comment: From `11.0.0` this sollution is not possible to use, because `zza` is marked as private.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is

```
Intent intent = AccountPicker.a(null, null,accountTypes, true, null, null, null, null, false, 1, 0);
```